# How to display Facebook comments sorter and more button?

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a Facebook iframe game and have used the following code to allow players to post comments:

```
<div class="comments">
<h1>Comments</h1>
<fb:comments data-href="http://www.facebook.com/xxxx/app_222222222222222" data-colorscheme="dark" data-width="440" data-order-by="reverse_time"></fb:comments>
</div>
```

I've seen other pages have a similar comments section but they have a dropdown sorter like this

[image]

Can you tell me how you get that sorter generated?

Also, they have a button you can press to show more comments as below:

[image]

Do you know how you generate that button?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is inherent to the plugin. Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/). It's possible that this option only appears if theres enough activity on the comments to begin with.